# Specflow features file not using step definitions

Tags: c#, .net-core, specflow

I created DotNetCore XUnit test project and am having trouble getting Specflow to work in it.

My feature file is in `\proj\Features\SpecflowFeatureFile.feature` and my step definitions are in `\proj\SpecflowFeatureSteps.cs`. When I run my tests I get this error:

> Error Message:
> TechTalk.SpecFlow.xUnit.SpecFlowPlugin.XUnitPendingStepException :
> Test pending: No matching step definition found for one or more steps.
> using System; using TechTalk.SpecFlow;
>
> namespace MyNamespace {
> [Binding]
> public class StepDefinitions
> {
> private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;
>
> ```
>     public StepDefinitions(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
>     {
>         _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
>     }
>     [Given(@"the deployment script has been installed")]
>     public void GivenTheDeploymentScriptHasBeenInstalled()
>     {
>         _scenarioContext.Pending();
>     }
>
>     [Given(@"the publisher has been installed")]
>     public void GivenThePublisherHasBeenInstalled()
>     {
>         _scenarioContext.Pending();
>     }
>
>     [When(@"the process status is checked")]
>     public void WhenTheProcessStatusIsChecked()
>     {
>         _scenarioContext.Pending();
>     }
>
>     [Then(@"the process should be running")]
>     public void ThenTheProcessShouldBeRunning()
>     {
>         _scenarioContext.Pending();
>     }
> } }
> ```

This is my feature file:

```
Feature: MyFeature
    Integration test for Publisher

@mytag
Scenario: Check the publisher is running
    Given the deployment script has been installed
    And the publisher has been installed
    When the process status is checked
    Then the process should be running
```

and this is the steps definition:

```
class MyFeatureSteps
{
    [Given(@"the deployment script has been installed")]
    public void GivenTheDeploymentScriptHasBeenInstalled()
    {
        Repository.Clone("ssh://git@mystash.com/proj/deployment.git", @".\EnvSetup");
    }

    [Given(@"the publisher has been installed")]
    public void GivenThePublisherHasBeenInstalled()
    {
            
    }

    [When(@"the process status is checked")]
    public void WhenTheProcessStatusIsChecked()
    {
            
    }

    [Then(@"the process should be running")]
    public void ThenTheProcessShouldBeRunning()
    {
            
    }

}
```

I tried the steps on [this](https://specflow.narkive.com/3TWGf4N9/go-to-definition-gets-no-matching-step-binding-found-for-this-step-for-existing-steps) page but they made no difference.

How can I get the features file to use the correct step difinitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `[Binding]` Attribute on your step class.

```cs
[Binding]
class MyFeatureSteps
{
    [Given(@"the deployment script has been installed")]
    public void GivenTheDeploymentScriptHasBeenInstalled()
    {
        Repository.Clone("ssh://git@mystash.com/proj/deployment.git", @".\EnvSetup");
    }

    [Given(@"the publisher has been installed")]
    public void GivenThePublisherHasBeenInstalled()
    {
            
    }

    [When(@"the process status is checked")]
    public void WhenTheProcessStatusIsChecked()
    {
            
    }

    [Then(@"the process should be running")]
    public void ThenTheProcessShouldBeRunning()
    {
            
    }

}
```